# I cant figure out how to get background colour in turtle python to work

Tags: python-turtle

I've been trying to figure out how to input background colour for a day or two now.
I have been given a booklet to work through as I learn however once I reached the chapter on setting a screen size or background colour, it simply wont work.
I was told to use the code `bgcolor("colour here")` and when that didn't work, I searched online and found `turtle.bgcolor("colour here")` which didn't work either.

All I get back is an error saying the names aren't defined. `setup(number 1, number 2)` was also coming up with the same error but i couldn't find a substitute to it online. Could somebody please help me?

my teacher said just fill a shape for the background but I feel like it would feel more achieving if I figured it out instead. Thank You

below is a few clips of my codes.

[image: Below it says line 2 is undefined (does the same for line 3)]

[image: Name is apparently undefined]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, copy and paste the code in here with `\`\`\`python` (press enter) (paste code here) (press enter again) `\`\`\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `from turtle import*` into `from turtle import *` (extra space)

So your code will be:

```py
from turtle import *
setup(800, 500)
bgcolor("black")
```

Comment: thank you although the names are still saying they aren't defined, did I miss a line that was meant to define them?

Comment: if you say `from turtle import *`, then you can directly call commands like `setup(num_1, num2)` and `bgcolor(color)`. However, if you want to say `turtle.setup(num_1, num_2)` or `turtle.bgcolor(color)`, then you need to change the first line to be just `import turtle`. With the `*`, that means that it imports every thing and has it in the default namespace, but just importing the library requires you to do `the_library.method()`

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a little bit. It seems to work on python but not python with turtle. (i use Repl.it)